# Why is the Layout style being applied to all of my JPanels?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

I am giving myself a crash course on re-learning Java. I am writing a very simple program that simply changes the place of the button when you click it to a random panel. There is no real problem, I pretty much finished the program that I wanted. However, I was wondering why is it that when I apply the Layout Style to the first panel (buttonPanel1), it is automatically applied to every panel?

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package buttonswitch;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.border.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.*;

/**
 *
 * @author Supreme Lenova
 */
import java.util.Random;
public class ButtonWindow extends JFrame{

    private JPanel buttonPanel1;
    private JPanel buttonPanel2;
    private JPanel buttonPanel3;
    private JPanel buttonPanel4;
    private JButton Button;

    private Border raisedbevel, loweredbevel;
    private Border compound;

    public ButtonWindow(){
        setTitle("Button Game");
        setLocation(600,50);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(2,2);
        setLayout(grid);

        raisedbevel = BorderFactory.createRaisedBevelBorder();
        loweredbevel = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        compound = BorderFactory.createCompoundBorder(raisedbevel, loweredbevel);

        buildPanels();

        Button = new JButton("Click!");
        Button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
        Button.addActionListener(new ButtonListener());

        buttonPanel1.add(Button);
        buttonPanel1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());

        setSize(300,300);
        setVisible(true);

}
    private void buildPanels(){
        buttonPanel1 = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel3 = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel4 = new JPanel();

        buttonPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS)); 
        buttonPanel1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());


        buttonPanel1.setBorder(compound);
        buttonPanel2.setBorder(compound);
        buttonPanel3.setBorder(compound);
        buttonPanel4.setBorder(compound);


        this.add(buttonPanel1);
        this.add(buttonPanel2);
        this.add(buttonPanel3);
        this.add(buttonPanel4);
    }



    private class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            generateButton();

        }

        private void generateButton(){
        int last = 5;
        int place = 5;
        Random rand = new Random();
        while(place==last){
        place = rand.nextInt(4)+1;
        }
        last = place;

        switch (place){

            case 1:
                repaint();
                buttonPanel1.add(Button);
                break;
            case 2:
                repaint();
                buttonPanel2.add(Button);
                break;
            case 3:
                repaint();
                buttonPanel3.add(Button);
                break;
            case 4:
                repaint();
                buttonPanel4.add(Button);
                break;


        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: It doesn't apply the layout to the other panels. The default layout for a panel is the `FlowLayout`. You add all the panels to the frame which uses a `GridLayout`, so all the panels will have the same parent and each panel will be displayed in a different grid of the parent panel.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Though the reason I say it applies it to the other panels is because whenever I make a change to buttonPanel1, it changes the button on each of the panels. If I use GridLayout, the button becomes large and takes the entire space for every single panel. If I use BoxLayout, it repeats the layout for every panel. Is there something maybe that I'm not understanding? Which panel is the parent panel in your description? Thanks btw.

Comment: `If I use GridLayout, the button becomes large and takes the entire space for every single panel.` - Yes that is the way GridLayout works. Every cell is made the same size as the largest component added to the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting a layout manager to `buttonPanel1`

```
buttonPanel1.setLayout(new BoxLayout(buttonPanel1, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
buttonPanel1.add(Box.createVerticalGlue());
```

Does not change the layout manager to other panels which use `FlowLayout` by default.

It does effect the button size. Print out

```
System.out.println(Button.getSize()); //use button, not Button
```

Now change the layout manager of `buttonPanel1`

```
buttonPanel1.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
```

and change the code to add the button to the panel :

```
buttonPanel1.add(Button, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

and print again. 
The layout manager changes the initial size of the button. The `FlowLayout` manager of the other 3 panels, does not change the size.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That answered my question.